# How to add Google Play Services SDK to AppsFlyer Xamarin Android App?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, appsflyer

I need to track Google Advertising ID with AppsFlyer. In order to do that, I need to add Google Play Services SDK to my Xamarin Android App.

Official AppsFlyer binding manual offers me to add `GooglePlayServicesLib.dll` binding library to project. But if I add this library I have `Java error code 2` on build. It is known problem, I tried to fix it by setting `Java Max Heap Size` to 1G but no chance.

To bypass this problem Xamarin split google play services library to 20 separate NuGet packages. According to AppsFlyer integration guide we need to add

> We only use the ads packages from Google Services

therefore i tried to use only Ads package

```
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads" version="25.0.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid5" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="25.0.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid5" />
```

I receive `Warning:Google Play services SDK jar is missing` from AppsFlyer on launch

to summarize:
I can't build the project with full GooglePlayServicesLib and it looks like AppsFlyer does not see SDK with only Ads package. What I'm missing?